# Turn off all update feature of Firefox

Tags: firefox, plugins, auto-update

Situation: In my working network, there are some configurations that do not allow, a browser to connect to any sites, which are not in local net. Firefox always asks to update the java plugin, and always try to connect to `java.com`. If it cannot connect to java.com, it will not let the applet run. I don't want to update manual any plugin but with a clone, because I must administrate about 150 PCs. Since the computers are only in local net, no internet access, there are not any security problem. So I think I can turn the update feature off, absolutely!

The question is: how can I turn it off. I've tried in Tool -> Add-on -> Setting -> unmark the option: "Update add-on automatically". But the FF even try to connect to java.com.

Background Infos: Firefox 23, Java 7.25

Comment: Off-Topic.. [questions I should avoid asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Questions on **professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/about).

Comment: @ Adam Zap. I think my question is not Off-Topic, regard your link. I have search in google, try some config in about:config ect. And I think my question/problem is not only useful for me, but also for other administrator. My question is not about professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration. It is just about "how can I absolutely turn the auto update feature in Firefox."

Answer (score 0):

It wouldnt be a security bug if you wouldnt allow the download and running of external code. Please turn off auto updates. its a pain in the butt. Then fix it so it cant download and run code. or allow that stupid program flash player to open a site in the background and run java code.

Comment: It (firefox) does not connect to internet. It just works only in a LAN. So I have not to care about security. All I need it: it does not do any stupid update check, automatically block any plugins because they are insecure. It should just work as I has configured it and should not change any thing.